# when expression kotlin how to check when a & b

Tags: kotlin

I have some code need to check 3 conditions by using when how to use when expression do this

```
when (obj) {
    a == 1 -> doAIsOne()
    a -> doSomethingA()
    b -> doSomethingB()
}
```

or I just do this?

```
when (obj) {
    a -> when(a) {
        1 -> doAIsOne()
        else -> doSomethingA()
    }
    b -> doSomethingB()
}
```

Comment: To clarify, the first case corresponds to `obj == a == 1`?

Comment: yes to clarify obj == a == 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
when {
    obj == 1 && a == 1 -> doAIsOne()
    obj == a -> doSomethingA()
    obj == b -> doSomethingB()
}
```